# Create a custom Popup for tapped OverlayItems in a MapView

Tags: android, popup, overlay, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I've got a working `MapView` with `Overlays` on it. I've done the official MapView-Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

My problem is, that when I click on an icon, a `Dialog` is opened. Instead of this, I need a **Popup-Window** to be opened, directly above the tapped point, like this:

[image: MapView Overlay PopUp]

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: [See this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution! You could post it as an answer, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons
Great example.